# Find & Replace all numbers in a url in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm editing an sql database and need to find and replace the following.

```
/imagename-1.jpeg
```

to:

```
/imagename.jpg
```

and it goes all the way up to

```
/imagename-867.jpeg
```

I hope there's a way to do this with RegEx, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Regular Expression option <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

***Find What***:

```
-\d+\.jpeg
```

***Replace With:***

```
.jpg
```

---

**Explained:**

```
-               Hyphen character followed by
\d              any digit [0-9]
+               (one or more)
\.              a literal dot
jpeg            the word "jpeg"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are also changing the extension of files.

**Regex:** `-\d+\.jpeg`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `.jpg`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL0yJ4/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use regEx : `-\d*.jpeg`
It will find all "-1.jpeg" or "-1868.jpeg" and replace with ".jpg".

Demo :https://regex101.com/r/wY2tB6/1